# Is this user spamming for their employer?

Tags: discussion, answers, spam

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587341/3rd-party-multi-page-tiff-viewer/42033824#42033824) in the review queue and downvoted it because it felt like an advertisement. I didn't feel comfortable flagging it as spam since the affiliation with the company was disclosed in the answer.

Clicking through to the user's profile, I see:

- they've never asked a question
- almost all their answers are for off-topic questions (requests for software recommendations)
- all their answers are advertising for the company
- all their answers but one have been upvoted at least once

To be fair, some of the answers do include code that you could use, if you bought their software. And there are lot of off-topic questions that have been answered, especially by new users.

What most concerns me is that all the answers, even the lowest quality ones, have been upvoted; I guess that's my secondary question here. Is there a way to tell if there has been unusual voting in this particular case? I took my first look at the data explorer today, but it looks like votes are only tracked by day, at least to the outside world.

But my main question is, does disclosing an affiliation immunize you against spam flags?

Comment: you will never be able to figure out where these votes come from, and that is intended. The best you can do is flag one of these posts and say it is fishy. A mod will investigate

Comment: @Patrice yeah I was just thinking if I saw the upvotes happening within seconds of the answer, that it might indicate something suspicious.

Comment: @miken32: Nope, you'd be amazed at what people vote up. :-) But if necessary, SE employees (not moderators) can trace the votes to see if they indicate a ring. (A tricky determination to make...) And interesting that the account has been suspended "for voting irregularities."

Comment: Now I am seeing ads for that company on the right hand side!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Even if affiliation is disclosed, creating an account just to suggest use of a product is spam.  If an account is primarily being used to recommend a product, even if the affiliation is disclosed, flag for moderator attention and say as much.  You probably shouldn't use an actual "spam" flag here; this is something for a moderator to look into specifically.

If you suspect voting fraud, then you should also mention that in the flag.

Comment: Well it looks like this question has had the same effect, but good to know for the future. Thanks.